# Get element location relative to viewport with selenium/python

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium

I'm using the below code to take a screenshot and crop just the element I want. However, as Chrome only takes a screenshot of the viewport the top number is too large as it is counting from the top of the page. Is there a way to get the location relative to the viewport?

```
element = browser.find_element_by_xpath(locator)
browser.save_screenshot('screenshot.png')
location = element.location
size = element.size
im = Image.open('screenshot.png')           
left = location['x']
top = location['y']
right = location['x'] + size['width']
bottom = location['y'] + size['height']
im = im.crop((int(left), int(top), int(right), int(bottom)))
im.save('screenshot2.png')
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was able to make it work by scrolling to the element, scroll slightly up (to get out from under the header), then get the scroll position and subtract it from the top number

```
element = browser.find_element_by_xpath(locator)
browser.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)
browser.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0, -150);")
browser.save_screenshot('screenshot.png')
location = element.location
scroll = browser.execute_script("return window.scrollY;")
size = element.size
im = Image.open('screenshot.png')           
left = location['x']
top = location['y'] - scroll
right = location['x'] + size['width']
bottom = location['y'] + size['height'] - scroll
im = im.crop((int(left), int(top), int(right), int(bottom)))
im.save('screenshot2.png')
```

Comment: Please don't forget to come back and accept this as the answer. Thanks.

Comment: You can also use "window.pageYOffset" which is IE compatible.